How to get a fragment of an mp4 video file from the middle, but keep the file metadata using nodejs aws
export async function* initiateObjectStream(
  Key: string,
  start: number,
  end: number,
): AsyncGenerator<any, any, unknown> {
  const streamRange = `bytes=${start}-${end}`;

  const getObjectCommand = new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key,
    Range: streamRange,
  });

  const { Body: chunks} = await s3Client.send(getObjectCommand);


  for await (const chunk of chunks) {
    yield chunk;
  }
}

I'm using this function to get an mp4 video file that will be later streamed to an HTML video player
When the start = 0 parameter is passed to the function argument, everything works. Because the chunks of the video file are broadcast from the beginning. And the first chunks of the video have the necessary metadata that indicate to the HTML Video player that this is a video and it should be displayed
When I want to display the video not from the beginning, but from the middle, the start value is different. B from AWS, I receive a video fragment that no longer has the first chunks with metadata. Because of this, the HTML video player closes the stream after receiving the first 3 chunks in which it expects metadata
How can I get the first chunks with metadata of my file through aws and glue them with the chunks of the desired fragment?
Or how can I create the first metadata chunks myself? And what values should I specify in the metadata?
I was trying to add metadata by another chunks, but it didn't help me
export async function* initiateObjectStream(
  Key: string,
  start: number,
  end: number,
): AsyncGenerator<any, any, unknown> {
  const streamRange = `bytes=${start}-${end}`;

  const getObjectCommand = new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key,
    Range: streamRange,
  });

  const { Body: chunks } = await s3Client.send(getObjectCommand);

  //@ts-ignore
  const passThroughStream = new PassThrough();

  const ftypChunk = Buffer.alloc(28);
  ftypChunk.writeUInt32BE(28, 0);
  ftypChunk.write('ftyp', 4);
  ftypChunk.write('mmp4', 8);
  ftypChunk.write('isom', 12);
  ftypChunk.write('iso2', 16);
  ftypChunk.write('mp41', 20);
  ftypChunk.write('mp42', 24);

  const mdatChunk1 = Buffer.alloc(8);
  mdatChunk1.writeUInt32BE(8, 0);
  mdatChunk1.write('mdat', 4);

  const mdatChunk2Size = 303739;
  const mdatChunk2 = Buffer.alloc(8 + mdatChunk2Size, 0x01); // I dont know what I need to do on this part
  mdatChunk2.writeUInt32BE(8 + mdatChunk2Size, 0);
  mdatChunk2.write('mdat', 4);

  const moovChunkSize = 6202;
  const moovChunk = Buffer.alloc(8 + moovChunkSize, 0x02); // I dont know what I need to do on this part
  moovChunk.writeUInt32BE(8 + moovChunkSize, 0);
  moovChunk.write('moov', 4);

  passThroughStream.write(ftypChunk);
  passThroughStream.write(mdatChunk1);
  passThroughStream.write(mdatChunk2);
  passThroughStream.write(moovChunk);
  passThroughStream.end();

  for await (const chunk of passThroughStream) {
    yield chunk;
  }

  //@ts-ignore
  for await (const chunk of chunks) {
    yield chunk;
  }
}

I also tried to use this library in such a format to share method chunks with chunks of the video fragment itself, but that didn't help either.
const ffmpegStream = ffmpeg()
    .input(chunks)
    .format('mp4')
    .addOutputOptions(
      '-movflags +frag_keyframe+separate_moof+omit_tfhd_offset+empty_moov',
    )
    .on('error', function (err) {
      console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
    })
    .on('end', function () {
      console.log('Processing finished !');
    });

  const ffstream = ffmpegStream.pipe().on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('ffmpeg just wrote ' + chunk.length + ' bytes');
  });


You need to provide three testable links to the MP4 segment chunks (maybe make a testing bucket or folder). Link 1 is for the the first chunk with metadata, and then link 2 is for next given chunk, and finally link 3 is for a chunk that holds video from the middle.

PS: It's good and useful that you tried to make an MP4 header, but it's not clear how you are sending the bytes to the HTML5 player. Is it connected to some script file (that sends bytes into it?). If you really are using a script to feed bytes into the .src of a video tag, then is the problem related to a seek event? I suspect the video tag wants bytes of a keyframe (but you give a fragment's header & bytes)... Also consider that MediaSource API  with appendBuffer might work better with fragmented MP4.

Amazon S3 does not modify video content. It stores videos. Use the AWS Elemental MediaConvert service to perform the video modifications. MediaConvert is a file-based video transcoding service that can convert media files from one format to another, resize, add overlays, and perform other video processing tasks.
There is a related STO here -- AWS Elemental MediaConvert Video File trimming start and end duration

Do I understand correctly that with this I can get a video fragment with metadata and stream it to the front-end in an HTML player? That is, I need to get a video that starts with a timecode not from 00:00, but from 05:30 (5.5 minutes after the video starts). And with AWS Elemental MediaConvert, can I get my video that starts exactly at 05:30 and with the existing metadata?

Point here is you retrieve video from S3, perform modifications on the video using Media Convert Service, then return the video to the client where it will be rendered. S3 does not modify video content.

Let's assume that the video is 10 minutes long
I need to get a video segment from 5 minutes to 10 minutes
Can Media Convert Service trim my video so that it starts from 5 minutes to 10 minutes and return it with all the metadata so that it can be displayed correctly in an HTML player?
I need to do this more than once. I will be a webinar platform. I have a recorded video. It starts on schedule at a certain time. If the viewer comes in later, I have to give them the video stream not from the beginning, but from the moment they entered the room.

For example, a webinar stream starts at 2pm. The video is 1 hour long. The person comes in at 2:30 pm. You need to give him the video from 30 minutes to 60 minutes. And one webinar can have hundreds of viewers. To what extent can Media Convert Service help with this?

And I don't need to save the cropped file. It needs to be given to the user at the moment via streaming in html playeer

You have several options for playing a sub-clip from an asset:
[a] For a VOD source, you could extract a sub-clip from the original asset into a new asset using AWS Elemental MediaConvert. The MediaConvert job format supports time clipping. Other open source video utilities can also do time clipping if you care to do the necessary integration & ongoing maintenance. MediaConvert is probably the least work to integrate.
[b] For a live source such as the webinar you mentioned-- you could package the live stream with AWS Elemental MediaPackage and simply request the timespan you want from the endpoint cache (DVR startover window) by passing start & end times on the playback URL. This has several advantages:  It's instantaneous, supports DRM, and no separate asset creation is required. Startover cache exists for up to 14 days. During that time you can choose to harvest a timespan to a permanent VOD asset.
[c] Some players accept a start offset time and play duration parameters; ffplay supports this. If your target player has this support, you can pass the parameters to the player and have it present just the desired timespan.
